# JQuery Custom Image Checkbox code not toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to make a custom checkbox with my own images.

First I included JQuery and added the JQuery code for the required functionality:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

$("#moreinfo").change(function() {
   if(this.checked) {
       $(this).prev().attr("src", "checkbox_unchecked.gif");
   } else {
       $(this).prev().attr("src", "checkbox_checked.gif");
   }
});

 });

</script>


Next...here's the HTML:



 <label for="moreinfo">
    <img src="checkbox_unchecked.gif"/>
    <input name="moreinfo" type="checkbox" id="moreinfo" style="display:none">
    </label>
```

The unchecked image is there but when I click on it, it doesn't change/toggle.

I'm I missing something?

UPDATE:

Testing this full code locally and it's not working...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

$("#moreinfo").change(function() {
   if(this.checked) {
       $(this).prev().attr("src", "http://icdn.pro/images/en/v/e/verify-correct-icone-9268-48.png");
   } else {
       $(this).prev().attr("src", "http://www.theology.edu/Remata/Android/Help/wrongx_icon.png");
   }
});


 });

</script>

</title>




</head>
<body>



<label for="moreinfo">
    <img src="http://www.theology.edu/Remata/Android/Help/wrongx_icon.png"/>
    <input name="moreinfo" type="checkbox" id="moreinfo" style="display:none">
    </label>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working, you can check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fqfdY/).

Comment: I agree it's working there but see the full code above which I'm testing. Try it...it won't work for some reason :o/

Comment: It's not working because you wrote script codes into title tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
      $("#moreinfo").click(function() {
       var $img =  $(this).prev();
$img.attr("src", ($(this).checked)?"checkbox_checked.gif":"checkbox_unchecked.gif");

    });
```